# Comparing list of items with one of the column in DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a Datable with 2 columns (`ProjectId, ServerGroupID`)

```
DataTable projectRestrictionList = new DataTable();    
projectRestrictionList =
               GetProjectRestrictionDatatable(projectID, serverGroupIds);
```

I have a list of items `"sgRestrictedServerGroups"`

```
List<Dell.AFP.Entity.ServerGroup> sgRestrictedServerGroups =
               prjctInfoResponse.RestrictedServerGroupList;
```

Now I want to comapre this list of  `sgRestrictedServerGroups`with the column ServergroupId in the table and need that result in a list.

Can some one help on this?

Comment: and those 2 lists have the same columns...?

Comment: what will you want to be final result after compare. I mean what you wanna to be compare ?

Comment: The List of type Dell.AFP.Entity.ServerGroup contains an object of servergroup. It has 7 properties. In that I want to compare server group id with the above table projectRestrictionList of column servergroupIds. I need to prepare a list with the result of the common servergroups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is simple join of two sequences on server group id. Assume *ServerGroupID* contains integer values, and name of id property in your `ServerGroup` entity is `Id`:

```
var result = from r in projectRestrictionList.AsEnumerable()
             join sg in sgRestrictedServerGroups 
                  on r.Field<int>("ServerGroupID") equals sg.Id
             select sg;
```

Feel free to use property name and column type you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this linq statement using `join`:
 
Edit:

```
 var tabletolist = projectRestrictionList.AsEnumerable().ToList();
   var restricted =  from p in tabletolist 
                     join s in sgRestrictedServerGroups
                     on p.ServerGroupID equals s.ServerGroupID
                     select p;
```

Comment: It did nt work because here projectRestrictionList is a datatable and sgRestrictedServerGroups is a list of data type ServerGroup object